# Julia data frame - need to select rows based upon multiple columns being missing

Tags: dataframe, julia, rows

Help for the Julia  newbie
I have joined 2 dataframes and need to select rows that have columns that are missing.
The following pulls from one column, but I need to pull multiples.
I need to pull `:md5` and `:md5_1` and `:md5_2`.... that are missing.

```
@where(bwjoinout_1_2, findall(x -> (ismissing(x)), :md5)) # works
```

This pulls rows that have `:md5` as missing.

I am syntactically challenged!!

Regards and stay safe
Bryan Webb

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I completely understand what you want to do, but would this work for you?

```
julia> df = DataFrame(id = 1:3, x=[1, missing, 3], y=[1, 2, missing])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ id     x        y       
     │ Int64  Int64?   Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1        1        1
   2 │     2  missing        2
   3 │     3        3  missing 

julia> df[ismissing.(df.x) .| ismissing.(df.y), :]
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ id     x        y       
     │ Int64  Int64?   Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     2  missing        2
   2 │     3        3  missing
```

Answer (score 2):

or

```
filter(row -> any(ismissing, row[names(df, r"^md5")]), df)
```

which will leave in `df` all rows that have a `missing` value in any of the columns whose name starts with `"md5"`. This is not the most efficient way to do it, but I think it is simplest conceptually.

If you need maximum performance go along what François Févotte proposed, but it currently requires you to explicitly list columns you want to filter on (this [PR](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/pull/2496) will allow to make it more cleanly).

Comment: most appreciated

Answer (score 2):

used

```
bwmissows = bwjoinout_1_2[ismissing.(bwjoinout_1_2.md5) .| ismissing.(bwjoinout_1_2.md5_1), :]
```

worked like a charm
pulled rows that had a missing `md5` or `md5_1`

Thanks for your help
Stay safe!

i couldn't get the syntax

Regards
bryan

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `bwjoinout_1_2[.!completecases(bwjoinout_1_2, r"md5"), :]`.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.